# tfs package upload size limit

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to upload a custom TFS extension to our TFS server via Manage Extenstions. But, when I try to upload the package, TFS doesn't allow it because of the file size. It throws an exception as below (*Image attached for reference*).

> The files being added total 23.6 MB which exceeds the maximum total size allowed to be uploaded (20 MB).

I tried increasing the file upload limit in IIS as mentioned in this [link](http://www.owenwebs.com/2014/04/08/increase-iis-file-upload-limits/) . But it did not work.

Can someone please help.

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oml2V.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

We could not increase the size limitation now, as the error message said. Actually this is the limitation for uploading files through TFS web portal.

You could only upload files which do not exceed **20MB** in TFS web access. Thank you for your understanding. Suggest you submit a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services).

Comment: I know this is old, but.. just in case someone comes across it (like I did), check out https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops-blog/upload-error-the-extension-package-size-26272573-bytes-exceeds/ba-p/3048916

`DECLARE @keyvalues dbo.typ_keyvaluepairstringtablenullable;

INSERT @keyvalues

VALUES ('#\Configuration\Service\Gallery\LargeExtensionUpload\MaxPackageSizeMB\', '30')

 

exec prc_UpdateRegistry 1, @keyvalues`